# Body not taking whole device width on mobile device

Tags: html, css, media-queries

[image: Body not taking whole width]

When the page is displayed on PC or tablet width it works perfectly. When on phone the body leaves empty space on the right. It isn't margin, or padding. I have tried `width: 100%` and `width: 100vw`.

Although the @media part doesn't help too much. I'm using flexbox to position everything, the viewport is activated and I have tried using position absolute / fixed on the body, but nothing works.

```css
@media (max-width: 576px) {
  body {
    width: 100%;
  }
  main {
    width: 100%;
  }
  header {
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
  nav {
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
  a {
    margin: 0.5rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: what about `html{}` is this maybe not 100vw?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no image or other element witch's width is no longer than the device width?

Comment: What does it look like with `100vw`?

Comment: With 100vw it looks exactly the same, I promise.

Comment: Do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your head?